# Production URL for nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using [NextJs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) to build out an application. I have two different URL's for production and development and I want to access the corresponding URL to the environment for the client. I followed this [guide](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-dotenv) but my PROCESS.ENV.API_URL on development is empty.

Here are my files:

.env:

```
API_URL=https://my-staging-url.com
```

.env.production:

```
API_URL=https://my-production-url.com
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["inline-dotenv"]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-inline-environment-variables"]
    }
  }
```

}

Environment variable usage:

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

export const SET_QUERY = 'SET_QUERY';
export const CLEAR_SEARCH = 'CLEAR_SEARCH';
export const START_FETCHING_SEARCH = 'START_FETCHING_SEARCH';
export const SET_SEARCH_RESULTS = 'SET_SEARCH_RESULTS';
export const FETCHING_SEARCH_FAILED = 'FETCHING_SEARCH_FAILED';

export const getSearch = value => {
    const url = `${process.env.API_URL}search?q=${value}`; // THIS IS EMPTY
    console.log(url);
    return fetch(url);
};

// Implement search action
export const doSearch = query => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: START_FETCHING_SEARCH });
    return dispatch => {
        return getSearch(query).then(response => {
            dispatch({ type: SET_SEARCH_RESULTS });
        }, () => {
            dispatch({ type: FETCHING_SEARCH_FAILED });
        });
    };
};

export const clearSearch = () => dispatch => {
    return dispatch({ type: CLEAR_SEARCH })
};
```

Hope that helps, Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

you must've forgot to install plugin

simply you can paste this in your package json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.1.1"
  }
```

and run 
`npm install`

or you can run 
`npm install babel-plugin-inline-dotenv babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables --save -dev`

OR You can simply achieve this feature differently as per this guide [with-universal-configuration](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-universal-configuration)

.bablerc

```
{
"plugins":[
    ["transform-define", "./env-config.js"]
]
}
```

.env-config.js

```
const prod = 'production' === process.env.NODE_ENV

module.exports = {
    'process.env.API_URL': prod ? 'http://api.dev.com' : 'http://api.local.com/',
}
```

and in package json you should ve to install `babel-plugin-transform-define`

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the variable is not displayed on the page, try clearing the babel-loader cache:

```
 rm -rf ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader
```